# A fast algorithm for deciding if a given undirected graph contains a C4 subgraph

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, cycles

I'm looking for an algorithm for deciding if a given undirected graph G contains C4 as a sub graph, not necessarily induced. I'm not interested in finding such a cycle, if it exists.
I was told there exists an algorithm for sparse graphs with $O(|E|^{4/3})$ and one for dense graphs in $O(|V|^{3/2})$

I found the [following article by Alon/Yuster/Zwick](https://www.tau.ac.il/%7Enogaa/PDFS/ayz4.pdf), which solves the problem in **much** more generality than I hoped for. But it uses many previous results which I would rather not use, and I'm unable to understand it and simplify it for my much simpler case.

Thanks in advance

Comment: There are related or identical questions on math overflow. 

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/67960/cycle-of-length-4-in-an-undirected-graph

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/16393/finding-a-cycle-of-fixed-length